# Spring Sleuth - Tracing Failures

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

In a microservice environment I see two main benefits from tracing requests through all microservice instances over an entire business process.

1. Finding latency gaps between or in service instances
2. Finding roots of failures, whether technical or regarding the business case

With [Zipkin](http://zipkin.io/) there is a tool, which addresses the first issue. But how can tracing be used to unveil failures in your microservice landscape? I definitely want to trace all error afflicted spans, but not each request, where nothing went wrong.
As mentioned [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-spring-cloud-zipkin) a custom Sampler could be used.

> Alternatively, you may register your own Sampler bean definition and programmatically make the decision which requests should be sampled. You can make more intelligent choices about which things to trace, for example, by ignoring successful requests, perhaps checking whether some component is in an error state, or really anything else.

So I tried to implement that, but it doesn't work or I used it wrong.
So, as the blog post suggested I registered my own Sampler:

```
    @Bean
    Sampler customSampler() {
    return new Sampler() {
        @Override
        public boolean isSampled(Span span) {

            boolean isErrorSpan = false;
            for(String tagKey : span.tags().keySet()){
                if(tagKey.startsWith("error_")){
                    isErrorSpan = true;
                }
            }
            return isErrorSpan ;
        }
    };
}
```

And in my controller I create a new Span, which is being tagged as an error if an exception raises

```
private final Tracer tracer;

@Autowired
public DemoController(Tracer tracer) {
    this.tracer = tracer;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/calc/{i}")
public String calc(@PathVariable String i){
    Span span = null;
    try {
        span = this.tracer.createSpan("my_business_logic");
        return "1 / " + i + " = " + new Float(1.0 / Integer.parseInt(i)).toString();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        span.logEvent("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
        this.tracer.addTag("error_" + ex.hashCode(), ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
    finally{
        this.tracer.close(span);
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't work. If I request /calc/a the method Sampler.isSampled(Span) is being called before the Controller method throws a NumberFormatException. This means, when isSampled() checks the Span, it has no tags yet. And the Sampler method is not being called again later in the process. Only if I open the Sampler and allow every span to be sampled, I see my tagged error-span later on in Zipkin. In this case Sampler.isSampled(Span) was called only 1 time but HttpZipkinSpanReporter.report(Span) was executed 3 times.

So what would the use case look like, to transmit only traces, which have error spans ? Is this even a correct way to tag a span with an arbitrary "error_" tag ?

Answer (score 0):

The sampling decision is taken for a trace. That means that when the first request comes in and the span is created you have to take a decision. You don't have any tags / baggage at that point so you must not depend on the contents of tags to take this decision. That's a wrong approach.

You are taking a very custom approach. If you want to go that way (which is not recommended) you can create a custom implementation of a `SpanReporter` - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/SpanReporter.java#L30 . `SpanReporter` is the one that is sending spans to zipkin. You can create an implementation that will wrap an existing `SpanReporter` implementation and will delegate the execution to it only when some values of tags match. But from my perspective it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Ok, then I misinterpreted Sampler.isSampled(Span span) because only the first Span of a request, that hits a microservice barrier, is being considered by a Sampler. I take from your answer, that Sleuth is not supposed to be used for failure tracing as suggested in the spring.io blog post, I mentioned. However, is it possible to access the current HTTP status from a Span, or better: the entire HTTP header? In this case I could report only requests with an error status to zipkin.

Comment: That's not true. You can *ALSO* use Sleuth to trace failure. Due to Sampling remember that you will see in Zipkin only (by default) 10% of traces so you'll be able to trace failure if you actually sample it. With the 1.2.0 Sleuth version you'll be able to use Baggage. Over there you can put whatever you want and that context gets propagated further on through the whole system.

Comment: @marcin isSampled will be called for every span right? If i see impl of PercentageBasedSampler then there is a probability that few spans are missed out in a trace. Is tht not right?

Comment: No it's not right. Sampled is carried for a trace. If there was a sampling decision then it will be carried over to any span within a trace